# Problems with permissions on the API 23

Tags: android

In an activity (`MapsActivity`) of my app, a map is displayed for the user to select the places he wants. I am using the `ACCES_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions.

I created the `PermissioUtils class` to validate the permissions that are in `MapsActivity class`.

When access to `MapsActicity`, the app closes with a `FATAL EXCEPTION`

**logcat error**

```
11-28 13:18:50.053 12496-12496/luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos, PID: 12496
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos/luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                                                                                     at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1704)
                                                                                     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:459)
                                                                                     at luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:205)
                                                                                     at luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:171)
                                                                                     at luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:104)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**PermissionUtils class**

```
public class PermissionUtils {

/**
 * Solicita as permissões
 */
public static boolean validate(Activity activity, int requestCode, String... permissions) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        // Valida permissão
        boolean ok = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (! ok ) {
            list.add(permission);
        }
    }
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        // Tudo ok, retorna true
        return true;
    }

    // Lista de permissões que falta acesso.
    String[] newPermissions = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(newPermissions);

    // Solicita permissão
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, newPermissions, 1);

    return false;
}
}
```

**MapsActivity class**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
int location = -1;

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    String label = new Date().toString();

    try {
        List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);

        if (listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0) {

            label = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MainActivity.places.add(label);
    MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    MainActivity.locations.add(point);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point)
            .title(label)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    Intent i = getIntent();
    location = i.getIntExtra("locationInfo", -1);


    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    // Solicita as permissões
    String[] permissoes = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    };
    PermissionUtils.validate(this, 0, permissoes);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    if (location == -1 || location == 0) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))) {
                // Caso o usuário tenha negado a permissão anteriormente, e não tenha marcado o check "nunca mais mostre este alerta"
                // Podemos mostrar um alerta explicando para o usuário porque a permissão é importante.
            } else {
                // Solicita a permissão
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},0);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
            }
        } else {
            //Tudo OK
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))) {
            // Caso o usuário tenha negado a permissão anteriormente, e não tenha marcado o check "nunca mais mostre este alerta"
            // Podemos mostrar um alerta explicando para o usuário porque a permissão é importante.
        } else {
            // Solicita a permissão
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},0);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
        }
    } else {
        //Tudo OK
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {

    if (location != -1 && location != 0) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))) {
                // Caso o usuário tenha negado a permissão anteriormente, e não tenha marcado o check "nunca mais mostre este alerta"
                // Podemos mostrar um alerta explicando para o usuário porque a permissão é importante.
            } else {
                // Solicita a permissão
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},0);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
            }
        } else {
            //Tudo OK
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MainActivity.locations.get(location), 10));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MainActivity.locations.get(location)).title(MainActivity.places.get(location)));

    } else {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    for (int result : grantResults) {
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            // Alguma permissão foi negada
            alertAndFinish();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Se chegou aqui está OK
}

private void alertAndFinish() {
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name).setMessage("Para utilizar este aplicativo, você precisa aceitar as permissões.");
        // Add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))) {
                    // Caso o usuário tenha negado a permissão anteriormente, e não tenha marcado o check "nunca mais mostre este alerta"
                    // Podemos mostrar um alerta explicando para o usuário porque a permissão é importante.
                } else {
                    // Solicita a permissão
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},0);
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
                }
            } else {
                //Tudo OK
            }
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location userLocation) {

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude()), 10));


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://luizugliano.com.br.lugaresfavoritos/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use permissions (`getBestProvider()`) before you have gotten them from the user. Beyond that, please post the entire stack trace, and show what lines in that stack trace correspond to lines in the source code from your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited my question with the entire stack trace. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setUpMap()`, which you are calling indirectly from `onCreate()`, needs the permissions. You have not asked the user for those permissions yet.

Comment: Tks for your help. I edited my question by adding a permission that was missing in my validation conditions, but the same error is still continues.

Comment: @LuizHenriqueUgliano: That's because you are not waiting to configure the map. If you do not have the permission, you need to wait until you *get* the permission, such as by not doing the work until after `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/MyLocationMNC) demonstrates using Maps V2 with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 and handling the runtime permissions.